# Calling onCreateContextMenu method in android?

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

How to call `onCreateContextMenu` method when I make click on `ExpanadableListView` child element (it is not long touch just touch only).

Answer (score 3):

Setup `onClickListener` and call [openContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [registerForContextMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu(android.view.View))

```
registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
```

additionaly to this you must override:

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```